# Como pasar un Select y un input tipo Checkbox como arreglos bidimensionales dependientes a través de $POST a una tabla?

Tags: php, array, http-post

Tengo el siguiente formulario.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>ARREGLO_BID</title></head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="pruebados.php">
    <select name="form[][txtmateria]">
        <option selected value="">SELECCIONE MATERIA</option>
        <option value="ADMINISTRACION">ADMINISTRACION</option>
        <option value="COMERCIO">COMERCIO</option>
        <option value="SISTEMAS">SISTEMAS</option>
    </select>
    <label><input name="form[][txtgrado]" value="SALA_1" type="checkbox">SALA_1</label>
    <label><input name="form[][txtgrado]" value="SALA_2" type="checkbox">SALA_2</label>
    <label><input name="form[][txtgrado]" value="SALA_3" type="checkbox">SALA_3</label>
<input type="submit" name="btnenviar" value="ENVIAR">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Para el archivo que recibe el $POST, pruebados.php; realizo lo siguiente para formar la tabla:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['form'] ) ){
echo '<table border="1">';    
echo '<thead>';
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th>MATERIA</th>';
        echo '<th>GRADO</th>';
    echo '</tr>';
echo '</thead>';    
echo '<tbody>';    
foreach ( $_POST['form'] as $diam ) {
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>', $diam['txtmateria'],'</td>';
        echo '<td>', $diam['txtgrado'],  '</td>';
    echo '</tr>'; }
    echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table>';}
```

La idea es que, por ejemplo al seleccionar una materia esta se repita la cantidad de veces de selecciones del Checkbox en la tabla, si seleccionara una materia y dos Checkbox apareciera algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero tengo los siguientes errores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De acuerdo a las sugerencias de [Kleith](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/66539/kleith), modificando los atributos name  así:

```
<select name="form[txtmateria]">
<input name="form[txtgrado][]" type="checkbox">
```

Y reordenando en foreach para el archivo pruebados.php  e implementando un ciclo for para imprimir el arreglo dentro del foreach, así:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['form'] ) ){
echo '<table border="1">';    
echo '<thead>';
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th>MATERIA</th>';
        echo '<th>GRADO</th>';
    echo '</tr>';
echo '</thead>';    
echo '<tbody>';    
foreach ( $_POST['form'] as $txtgrado ) {
    for($x=0;$x<count($txtgrado);$x++){
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' .$_POST['form']['txtmateria'].'</td>';            
            echo '<td>' .$txtgrado[$x].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>'; } 
    }
echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table>'; }
```

Obtengo un pequeño detalle en la primera línea al imprimir (una letra "A" que nose de donde sale), siguiendo el ejemplo que propuse de seleccionar una materia y dos salones, que me afectaría al introducir a una BD, así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lograrlo deberías modificar los atributos `name` correctamente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>ARREGLO_BID</title></head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="pruebados.php">
    <select name="form[txtmateria]">
        <option selected value="">SELECCIONE MATERIA</option>
        <option value="ADMINISTRACION">ADMINISTRACION</option>
        <option value="COMERCIO">COMERCIO</option>
        <option value="SISTEMAS">SISTEMAS</option>
    </select>
    <label><input name="form[txtgrado][]" value="SALA_1" type="checkbox">SALA_1</label>
    <label><input name="form[txtgrado][]" value="SALA_2" type="checkbox">SALA_2</label>
    <label><input name="form[txtgrado][]" value="SALA_3" type="checkbox">SALA_3</label>
<input type="submit" name="btnenviar" value="ENVIAR">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Esto devuelve un `array` ordenado.

```
array(2) {
  ["form"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["txtmateria"]=>
    string(14) "ADMINISTRACION"
    ["txtgrado"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(6) "SALA_1"
    }
  }
  ["btnenviar"]=>
  string(6) "ENVIAR"
}
```

Y en el `pruebados.php`:

```
if (isset($_POST['form'])) {
  echo '<table border="1">';    
  echo '<thead>';
    echo '<tr>';
      echo '<th>MATERIA</th>';
      echo '<th>GRADO</th>';
    echo '</tr>';
  echo '</thead>';    
  echo '<tbody>';    
  foreach ($_POST['form']['txtgrado'] as $txtgrado ) {
    echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td>' . $_POST['form']['txtmateria'] . '</td>';
      echo '<td>' . $txtgrado . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
  }
  echo '</tbody>';
  echo '</table>';
}
```

Comment: Gracias implemente tus aportes al código, pero me surgio un error en la línea echo '<td>' . $txtgrado . '</td>'; la variable $txtgrado es un arreglo y no se puede imprimirla como cadena, así que implemente un ciclo for para imprimirla con el echo, coloco los resultados al actualizar la pregunta y ahora surgió otro pequeño error.

Comment: Si, perdón pero me olvidé de poner en el `foreach` el arreglo de `'txtgrado'`. Ahí lo actualicé, chequealo ahora, queda `foreach ($_POST['form']['txtgrado'] as $txtgrado ) {`.

Comment: Exelente, solo faltaba eso, resuelto el problema, lo del ciclo for que implemente resolvia parcialmente, tengo curiosidad que podria faltar para hacerlo con ciclo for, revisa mi actualizacion y me das alguna sugerencia.

Comment: Porque en el ciclo del `foreach` estás recorriendo `'txtmateria'` y `'txtgrado'`, y con esos resultados estás ejecutando un `for` que primero recorre `'txtmateria'` y te devuelve `'A'` porque dentro de `'txtmateria'` tenés un `string ('ADMINISTRACION')` que al devolver el primer valor, se encuentra con la letra inicial del string. Un poco enroscado el problema.